# How do I show a caret (^) in math mode in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, math-mode

I'm trying to display a caret (`^`) in math mode in LaTeX to represent the exclusive or operation implemented in the "C languages". By default, `^` is for creating a superscript in math mode. The closest I can seem to get is by using `\wedge`, which isn't the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, \wedge is the common symbol for AND (conjunction), so it's not a good idea to use a similar-looking character for exclusive OR. Unless you are typesetting code, in which case you should not be using math mode anyway.

Comment: I highly recommend the [short math guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) which includes a list of symbols.

Comment: This should go in latex overflow page

Comment: @Whitecat Do you mean `http://tex.stackexchange.com/`? I think old questions like this will not be migrated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might want to use the common symbol for exclusive or instead, \oplus (but give it a proper name with something like `\newcommand\XOR{\oplus}`).

The caret is a bit too small to be noticeable as a binary operator. However, if you do insist using a caret instead, use this:

```
\newcommand\XOR{\mathbin{\char`\^}}
$x \XOR y$
```

The `\mathbin` puts the right spacing around the symbol for a binary operator, and the `\char` ensures that the glyph is obtained from the roman font.

Comment: There are at least four "common symbols" for exclusive or, depending on context. I wanted the one used in the "C languages" which is the carat.

The real question that hasn't been mentioned is "why am I using math mode for code?" I probably should have just used a verbatim environment.

Comment: Good point with which symbol to use. Take a look at the listings package, if you haven't already. It can do code printing very nicely.

Answer (score 11):

Use the wedge symbol as a superscript. It has the perfect size.

Something like this:

```
$ ^\wedge $
```

Answer (score 10):

How about

```
\^{}
```

or

```
\verb|^|
```

?

Comment: \verb is never allowed inside the argument to other commands, so is of limited use for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 5):

Use `\textasciicircum` in text mode. If you are in math mode, you need to use something like `$\mbox{\textasciicircum}$`.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did:

```
$2\hat{\text{ }}3$
```

Answer (score 3):

Within math mode, you can use:

```
$7 \^{ } 3 = 4$
```

to do this, as shown from the online LaTeX renderer [here](http://thornahawk.unitedti.org/equationeditor/equationeditor.php).

[image]

Comment: Actually I found this editor seems to double backslashes before passing to LaTeX, so e.g. `\alpha\beta` produces the output *alpha* and then *beta* on the next line, rather than the actual Greek symbols for alpha and beta on a single line.  OTOH the "original" equation editor page worked: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 2):

`\^` is an accent character that applies to other characters, `\^{4}` gives a `4` with a carat on its head. It takes up no horizontal space. If you write `$7 \^{} 3 = 4$` you get a `73` with a mark smashed onto both the `7` and the `3`. What you need then is to fill out the space a little bit. Through trial and error and a nice application called LatexIt, I found this sequence to work beautifully:

```
\hspace{1.5} \^{} \hspace{1.5}
```

This gives a 3 unit width with the carat centered in it. It looks nice.

It is a pointy carat though, and `\verb|^|` gives a more flattened one that looks more like a monotype font frequently used in programming languages.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be the accepted answer. As noted below, \^ isn't valid in math mode. Furthermore, rather than inserting manual spaces, use \mathbin{} instead to get the spacing right (see fntguide.pdf).

Comment: I know it's not the cleanest answer, but it works on my machine, you know how that goes...

Comment: If by "works" you mean "gives an error" :)
I think it's a bad design decision that some LaTeX IDEs are set up to scroll past all the errors and warning.